# Como hacer una consulta en un documento e insertar el resultado en otro documento

Tags: mongodb

Necesito obtener el _id de un documento e insertarlo en otro documento junto con otros datos-

Lo que deseo es tener dos documentos que se puedan relacionar, teniendo el _id del documento principal como campo del documento secundario

En Mongodb

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar una consulta en un documento de MongoDB y luego insertar el resultado en otro documento, utilizando su lenguaje de consulta y manipulación de datos, que es el lenguaje de consultas basado en JavaScript podrías probar los guisiente:

1. Realiza la consulta en el documento utilizando el método `find()`:

```javascript
const consulta = db.sourceCollection.find({ id: "documento_id" });
```

2. Almacena el resultado de la consulta en una variable:

```javascript
const resultadoConsulta = consulta.toArray();
```

3. Inserta el resultado en otro documento utilizando el método `insertOne()` o `insertMany()` según tus necesidades. Por ejemplo, supongamos que tienes una colección llamada "destinationCollection" y quieres insertar el resultado de la consulta en un nuevo documento:

```javascript
db.destinationCollection.insertOne(resultadoConsulta);
```

Reemplazar "sourceCollection", "documento_id" y "destinationCollection" con los nombres de tu colección y campo de documento correspondientes.